# Google maps marker does not show JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: 'pointer.png',
    title: "test"
});
```

My map loader perfect, but my marks will not appear.

I do not quite understand why it is happening?

edit 1:

Here is the whole function, I hope it will help answer some of your questions:

```
 function initMap() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 16,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $userRow['latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $userRow['longitude']; ?>),
     });
     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

     // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
     downloadUrl('http://xxx.esy.es/test/test-marker.php', function(data) {
         var xml = data.responseXML;
         var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
         Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
             var name = markerElem.getAttribute('username');
             var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                 parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('latitude')),
                 parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('longitude')));

             var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
             var strong = document.createElement('strong');
             strong.textContent = name
             infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
             infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

             var text = document.createElement('text');
             text.textContent = address
             infowincontent.appendChild(text);
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: point,
                 icon: 'pointer.png',
                 title: "test"
             });
             marker.addListener('click', function() {
                 infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                 infoWindow.open(map, marker);
             });
         });
     });
 }
```

Edit 2

here it my xml code, it works fine! it is just my marker on the map that do not work

```
<?php
include_once 'test-dbconnect.php';
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}


header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

 $sql = "select * from tbl_users";
    $result = mysqli_query($DBcon, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($DBcon));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;

  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['username']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['latitude'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['longitude'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}


    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($DBcon);

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Comment: are you throwing any javascript errors?  Are you sure your image path is correct?

Comment: I dont get any errors, and yes i'm sure that my image path is correct.

Comment: keep the given code on map 'idle' event

Comment: What is `map`? What is `point`?  Where is this code executed? ([it works for me if the answers to those questions make sense](http://jsfiddle.net/rutjLdmu/)) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: under my developer tool in the chrome browser i can see the pointer, it just dont show up on the map

Comment: Your "complete" code isn't very useful without any XML to create markers.  Second request: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: check my edit 2 there is my XML code

Comment: Use your javascript console! And debug your code. Is `point` what you expect? Is `'pointer.png'` available (meaning it is in the same directory than you javascript file)? etc.

Comment: it is Maybe a little dum... but i dont know how to use it..
here is the link: http://hejmeddig.esy.es/test/test-map.php
the login is: test@test.dk
the password is: test

Comment: @MrUpsidown could you maybe help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML:

```
<marker name="test" address="sømærket 3 hørsholm" lat="55.880875" lng="12.448797"/>
```

In your JS:

```
markerElem.getAttribute('latitude')
```

You are using `lat` and `latitude`, `lng` and `longitude`, `name` and `username`. So make sure you use the right attributes!

---

You could easily debug your code by using this simple line in you JS:

```
console.log(markerElem.getAttribute('latitude'));
```

And watch your javascript console (in a decent browser like Chrome or Firefox). If you don't know where it is, please check your browser documentation.

Comment: Thanks! that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Check if 'map' is in scope.

Also, keep this code code in map's idle event:

```
var marker = null;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {


   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: 'pointer.png',
        title: "test"
   });
});
```

Comment: pls provide a fiddle

Comment: what is a fiddle?

Comment: Out of curiosity , are the markers in the area shown by the map , like near the center ?

Comment: i hav zoomed out, you can check it out your self http://hejmeddig.esy.es/test/test-map.php

Comment: need a login for that link

Comment: the login is: test@test.dk 
the password is: test

Comment: could you maybe help me out?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Call your div

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 520px; border: 1; border-color: #000;" class="centered"></
<!-- This is the div that will contain the Google Map -->
```

In a Script:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

And put your marker properties and icon, try it with JSON:

```
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
                'map': map,
                'title': item.PlaceName
            });

            // Set Icon

            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png')

            // put in some information about each json object - in this case, the opening hours.
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<div class='infoDiv'>\n\<h2 class='text-center'>" + item.PlaceName + "</h2></div></div>"
            });

            // finally hook up an "OnClick" listener to the map so it pops up out info-window when the marker-pin is clicked!
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        })
```

Comment: i need to take data from a xml file, so will that work?

Comment: You are using _Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem)_ ... it's the same.